An inequality about expectations of convex function in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Recently I'm solving questions in Durrett's PTE(5th edition). In question"1.6.2. Suppose $\varphi: \mathbf{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is convex. Imitate the proof of Theorem 1.5.1 to show
$$
E \varphi\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right) \geq \varphi\left(E X_1, \ldots, E X_n\right)
$$
provided $E\left|\varphi\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right)\right|<\infty$ and $E\left|X_i\right|<\infty$ for all $i$.", I tried the following procedures to construct the linear function (hyperplane) $l$ such that $l(\vec{x}) \le \varphi(\vec{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:

Denote that $\vec{x}_0=\left(\mathbb{E} X_1, \mathbb{E} X_2, \ldots, \mathbb{E} X_n\right)$ and $\vec{h}=\frac{\vec{x}_0}{\left|\vec{x}_0\right|}$. By convexity,
$$
  \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right)-\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0-\varepsilon \vec{l}\right)}{|\varepsilon \vec{l}|} \leqslant \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0+\varepsilon \vec{l}\right)-\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right)}{|\varepsilon \vec{l}|}
  $$
where $\vec{l}$ is any non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Denote $e_i=(0, \ldots, 0,1,0, \ldots, 0), i=1,2, \ldots, n$. For $\forall i$ we let $\vec{l}=\vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{h}$, then we can get $a_i$ : any number between
$$
  \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right)-\varphi\left(\vec{x}-\varepsilon \vec{e}_i \vec{h}_h\right)}{\left|\varepsilon \vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{h}\right|} \text { and } \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0+\varepsilon \vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{k}\right)-\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right)}{\left|\varepsilon \vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{k}\right|}
  $$
Then denote $\vec{a}=\left(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\right)$ and let
$$
  l(\vec{x})=\vec{\alpha} \cdot\left(\vec{X}-\vec{x}_0\right)+\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right), \vec{X}=\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n
  $$
Now we want to show
$$
> l(\vec{X}) \leqslant \varphi(\vec{X})
> $$
Then taking expectations we get
$$
  \begin{aligned}
 & \vec{a} \cdot\left(\mathbb{E} X_1, \ldots, \mathbb{E} X_n\right)-\vec{\alpha} \cdot \overrightarrow{x_0}+\varphi\left(\vec{x}_0\right) \leq \mathbb{E}(\varphi(\vec{X})) \\
 & \overset{\text { Recall def }}\Leftrightarrow \varphi\left(\mathbb{E} X_1, \mathbb{E} X_2, \ldots, \mathbb{E} X_n\right) \leq \mathbb{E}\left(\varphi\left(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\right)\right)
  \end{aligned}
 $$

However I get stuck in proving "$l(\vec{X}) \leqslant \varphi(\vec{X})$". I want to prove it on the contrary(assuming that if there is a point $\vec{y}=(y_{1},y_{2},\dots,y_{n})$ such that $l(\vec{y}) \gt \varphi(\vec{y})$, then I get stuck in finding the contradiction in
$$
(a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n})\cdot (y_{1} - \mathbb{E}X_{1},y_{2} - \mathbb{E}X_{2},\dots,y_{n} - \mathbb{E}X_{n}) > \varphi(\vec{y}) - \varphi(\mathbb{E}X_{1},\mathbb{E}X_{2},\dots,\mathbb{E}X_{n})
$$
)
Can anyone give me a hint or solution? Thanks for your help!

Let $g \in \partial \phi(EX)$ be a subdifferential of $\phi$ at $EX$. Then, by definition,
$\phi(X) - \phi(EX) \ge g^T (X-EX)$ for all $X$. Taking expectation shows that $E\phi(X) - \phi(EX) \ge g^T(EX-EX) = 0$.
